# How to Make Math.Round for a Number

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

how to make the Rounded number  ?

Example : 3341.48 to 3342.00

Comment: Your answer is in your question's title, which makes me think you want something more than just Math.Round(3341.48). Am I right?

Comment: thnx for reply . but answer is not in title

Comment: The answer to "how to make the rounded number" is indeed in the title. Which again, makes me think you want something else. I do not however know what that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you always want to round up here. In that case use

```
Math.Ceiling(3341.48)
```

This will return 3342.

If you want to round towards the nearest whole number, use

```
Math.Round(3341.48)
```

This will return 3341. Note that `Bankers rounding`is the default setting here, that might cause some unexpected result for rounding X.50.

Comment: thnx for reply. here i need to make the round the number as 3342.00

Answer (score 0):

If you want 3341.48 to round up to 3342, it sounds like you might want [`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cz5da1c.aspx):

```
decimal m = 3341.48m;
decimal roundedUp = Math.Ceiling(m);
```

This will *always* round up - so 3341.0000001 would still round to 3342, for example. If that's not what you're after, please specify the circumstances in which you want it to round up, and those in which you want it to round down instead.

Note that this will round up to 3342, not 3342.00 - it doesn't preserve the original precision, because you've asked for an integer value by using `Math.Ceiling`.

It's relatively unusual to then want to *force* the precision to 2, but you *could* divide by 100 and then multiply by 100 again, if necessary. Alternatively, if you only need this for *output* you should look into formatting the result appropriately rather than changing the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.Round(number)` if you want to round `number` to the nearest integer.
Use `Math.Round(number,digits)` if you want to round `number` to a specified number of fractional digits.
If you want to round to lower/higer value use `Math.Floor(number)` / `Math.Ceiling(number)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To round monetary amounts to 5 cents:

amount = 20 * int(amount / 20)